# SPA + Spring Security: How to avoid redirect to login page in Spring Security?

Tags: spring-mvc, extjs, spring-security, single-page-application

I have a single-page web application, which uses ExtJS.
It has single index.html, which implements both login functionality and application functionality: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/tutorials/login_app.html

I am trying to configure Spring Security to work with such SPA client:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
public class UrlSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()//
            .antMatchers("/index.html").permitAll()//
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/authenticate").permitAll()//
            .anyRequest().authenticated()//
            .and()//
            .formLogin()//
            .failureUrl("/index.html")//
            .loginProcessingUrl("/authenticate")//
            .loginPage("/index.html").permitAll().and()//
            .logout().deleteCookies("remember-me")//
            .and().rememberMe()//
            .and().csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

If I specify loginPage("/index.html"), Spring Security redirects to index.html.

If I specify loginPage(), Spring Security generates login page.
How can I configure Spring Security not to redirect to loginPage?

Comment: I understand from your question, that you want to avoid the redirection to the /index.html, but in what scenario, no user in session? log-in failure?

Comment: Routing in SPA should happen on the client, not on the server.